# Multi threading script for HTTP status codes

Tags: python, multithreading, curl, http-status

Hi Stackoverflow community,

I would like to create a script that uses multi threading to create a high number of parallel requests for HTTP status codes on a large list of URL's (more than 30k vhosts).

The requests can be executed from the same server where the websites are hosted.

I was using multithreaded curl requests, but I'm not really satisfied with the results I've got. For a complete check of 30k hosts it takes more than an hour.

I am wondering if anyone has any tips or is there a more performant way to do it?

Comment: libcurl is really good at async'ing multiple connections on a single thread, which should be much more efficient than running a thread per connection, check the [libcurl multi interface](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing some of the available solutions, the simplest and the fastest way was using webchk

> webchk is a command-line tool developed in Python 3 for checking the HTTP status codes and response headers of URLs

The speed was impressive, the output was clean, it parsed 30k vhosts in about 2 minutes

https://webchk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

https://pypi.org/project/webchk/

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for parallelism and multi-threaded approaches to make HTTP requests with Python, then you might start with the `aiohttp` library, or use the popular `requests` package. Multithreading can be accomplished with `multiprocessing`, from the standard library.

Here's a discussion of rate limiting with aiohttp client: [aiohttp: rate limiting parallel requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682147/aiohttp-rate-limiting-parallel-requests)

Here's a discussion about making multiprocessing work with `requests` https://stackoverflow.com/a/27547938/10553976

Making it performant is a matter of your implementation. Be sure to profile your attempts and compare to your current implementation.