# using python requests to speed up for loop

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python code and I want to speed it up using threads but when I try to I get the same lines getting duplicated, is there is any way I could speed it up without getting duplicate lines

code

```py
import requests
import json

f = open("urls.json")
data = json.load(f)
def urls():
    for i in data['urls']:
        r = requests.get("https://" + i)
        print(r.headers)
```

Comment: Split the data urls into e.g. ten chunks and let each thread handle one of those chunks.

Comment: [Multiprocessing HTTP get requests in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547170/multiprocessing-http-get-requests-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for that , can you put a piece of code as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ThreadPoolExecutor` class from [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html). It is efficient way according to `Thread` class.

You can change the `max_workers` value according to your task

Here is the piece of code:

```py
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import json

with open("urls.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

def urls():
    urls = ["https://" + url for url in data['urls']]
    print(urls)

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as pool:
        iterator = pool.map(requests.get,urls)

    for response in iterator:
        print(response.headers)
        print("\n")
```

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, don't forget to close the file if you don't need the file object `f`.  Closing the file before program finishes is good practise

Answer (score 0):

Make `async` or `threaded` calls.

So, you would do something like this:

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

start_time = time.time()


async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        for number in range(1, 151):
            pokemon_url = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{number}'
            async with session.get(pokemon_url) as resp:
                pokemon = await resp.json()
                print(pokemon['name'])

asyncio.run(main())
```

Could also do multiprocessing as per the comment, but async is better for i/o type tasks.